# is it possible to cast a @Entity object to a plain object without affecting the first?

Tags: java

I am currently trying to do this:

I have my model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    ...
```

And I have other object, lets say PlainStudent

```
public class PlainStudent{

   private long id;
   private String name;

... other fields
```

How could be possible to cast Student to a PlainStudent when Student is an Entity? I dont know how to make them both implement same interface and I dont know if is possible. Any ideas?

I have my studentRepository and basically I need to return a list of Students to later cast them to PlainStudent (dont know if I have to update my repository to return PlainStudent as well)

And where should I place my annotations?

Comment: `@Entity` is just metadata used by JPA. It doesn't really have to do with class casting or inheritance. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Well `Student` would have to extend `PlainStudent` as for starters

Comment: Ive edited my post ,please take a look

Comment: Do you want to cast? Or treat the PlainStudent as a DTO?

Comment: I don't think you need the PlainStudent class at all.  The Entity Student class appears to be identical to PlainStudent except for the Entity annotation.  You can create, update, and/or delete as many Entity Student objects as necessary, and nothing you've done will be persisted to the repository until you call save, update, or delete on the repository and pass in the actual Entity object to be saved, updated, or deleted.

Comment: Just implement common interface as you wanted. JPA/HIbernate entities can implement interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you would need it, because the JPA annotations have no effect outside of JPA, but if you do you could write a constructor:

```
PlainStudent (Student student) { this.id = student.id; this.name = student.name; ...}
```

And then use it:

> PlainStudent plainStudent = new PlainStudent (student);

BTW, JPA supports inheritance: ["Entities may extend both entity and non-entity classes, and non-entity classes may extend entity classes."](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html). So if Student were to extend PlainStudent you could use a cast. But then in Student you would have to annotate the getters, as the variables would be inherited.